# filter array into different array on the basis of fields

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array as follows:

```
[
  {
            "values": [
              {
                "title": "Status",
                "text": "closed"
              },
              {
                "title": "Timeline",
                "text": "2021-12-06 - 2021-12-24"
              }
            ]
    },
      {
            "values": [
              {
                "title": "Status",
                "text": "overdue"
              },
              {
                "title": "Timeline",
                "text": "2021-12-06 - 2021-12-24"
              }
            ]
    },
      {
            "values": [
              {
                "title": "Status",
                "text": "open"
              },
              {
                "title": "Timeline",
                "text": "2021-12-06 - 2021-12-24"
              }
            ]
    },
      {
            "values": [
              {
                "title": "Status",
                "text": "open"
              },
              {
                "title": "Timeline",
                "text": "2021-12-06 - 2021-12-24"
              }
            ]
    },
      {
            "values": [
              {
                "title": "Status",
                "text": "closed"
              },
              {
                "title": "Timeline",
                "text": "2021-12-06 - 2022-01-29"
              }
            ]
    }
]
```

I want my final output in three arrays closedArray,openArray,dueArray.
I want to traverse this array, go to status field, check status. if status is closed, then put element in closedArray, if overdue then put element in due array, if open put element in open array. If date in Timeline field passed the current date, then need to put that element in openArray. How can I do this?

Comment: You're asking someone to write all this code for you.  Much better to show which part are you having trouble with

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck? Please have a look at [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/14201528) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Hey please check this out:

```js
const results = {};
const array=[{values:[{title:"Status",text:"closed"},{title:"Timeline",text:"2021-12-06 - 2021-12-24"}]},{values:[{title:"Status",text:"overdue"},{title:"Timeline",text:"2021-12-06 - 2021-12-24"}]},{values:[{title:"Status",text:"open"},{title:"Timeline",text:"2021-12-06 - 2021-12-24"}]},{values:[{title:"Status",text:"open"},{title:"Timeline",text:"2021-12-06 - 2021-12-24"}]},{values:[{title:"Status",text:"closed"},{title:"Timeline",text:"2021-12-06 - 2022-01-29"}]}];


array.forEach(e => (
   new Date(e.values[1].text.split(" - ")[1]) > new Date() ? // check if date has passed
      results["open"]?.push(e) || (results["open"] = [e]) : // if yes -> add to open array
   results[e.values[0].text]?.push(e) || (results[e.values[0].text] = [e]) // else add to other key
));

const {open, closed, overdue} = results;
console.log("openArray", open);
console.log("closedArray", closed);
console.log("overdueArray", overdue);
```

Comment: I want to output in three array, could you please update your code?

Comment: "I want to output in three array"? Fix your question and add the output you want to get!

Comment: if status is closed then element should be in closed array, if status is overdue then output in due Array and for open in open array

Comment: Yeah this is exactely what you get with this answer!

Comment: you are not pushing elements anywhere in arrays at end. Seems they are objects

Comment: where did you defined three arrays?

Comment: this is wrong, could you please go throught question again